# python nested lists not splitting

Tags: python, list, nested

So I have the following nested list in python:

```
a=[['1475367347', '72', 'c82e4f74ab2856bf', '14e87da06de28007', '1faf45a4', '83f8e8c8', '6', 'c7bd96e2', 'c7bd96e2', 'a799a5bf', '4b664dcf', '5d955804', '3d2831f2', '1', '1'],['1475367347', '72', 'c82e4f74ab2856bf', '14e87da06de28007', '1faf45a4', '83f8e8c8', '6', 'c7bd96e2', 'c7bd96e2', 'a799a5bf', '4b664dcf', '5d955804', '3d2831f2', '1', '1']]
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
for b in a:
    for item in b:
        print(item)
```

But the result of the above print statement is as follows:

```
[
[
'
1
4
7
5
3
6
7
3
4
7
'
,

'
7
2
'
,

'
c
8
2
e
4
f
7
4
a
b
2
8
5
6
b
f
'
,

'
1
4
e
8
7
d
a
0
6
d
e
2
8
0
0
7
'
,

'
1
f
a
f
4
5
a
4
'
,

'
8
3
f
8
e
8
c
8
'
,

'
6
'
,

'
c
7
b
d
9
6
e
2
'
,

'
c
7
b
d
9
6
e
2
'
,

'
a
7
9
9
a
5
b
f
'
,

'
4
b
6
6
4
d
c
f
'
,

'
5
d
9
5
5
8
0
4
'
,

'
3
d
2
8
3
1
f
2
'
,

'
1
'
,

'
1
'
]
,
[
'
1
4
7
5
3
6
7
3
4
7
'
,

'
7
2
'
,

'
c
8
2
e
4
f
7
4
a
b
2
8
5
6
b
f
'
,

'
1
4
e
8
7
d
a
0
6
d
e
2
8
0
0
7
'
,

'
1
f
a
f
4
5
a
4
'
,

'
8
3
f
8
e
8
c
8
'
,

'
6
'
,

'
c
7
b
d
9
6
e
2
'
,

'
c
7
b
d
9
6
e
2
'
,

'
a
7
9
9
a
5
b
f
'
,

'
4
b
6
6
4
d
c
f
'
,

'
5
d
9
5
5
8
0
4
'
,

'
3
d
2
8
3
1
f
2
'
,

'
1
'
,

'
1
'
]
]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you are simply printing the elements, how can you expect them to split by themselves?

Comment: I don't think that your example for `a` matches what you're using. Instead of being a nested list, you have a _string representation_ of the nested list e.g. `a="[[1, 2, 3]]"`. The raw data of your actual output is a big list with single items on each line? I think the SO editor has gone some way to formatting it back to what you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> a="""[['1475367347', '72', 'c82e4f74ab2856bf', '14e87da06de28007', '1faf45a4', '83f8e8c8', '6', 'c7bd96e2', 'c7bd96e2', 'a799a5bf', '4b664dcf', '5d955804', '3d2831f2', '1', '1'],['1475367347', '72', 'c82e4f74ab2856bf', '14e87da06de28007', '1faf45a4', '83f8e8c8', '6', 'c7bd96e2', 'c7bd96e2', 'a799a5bf', '4b664dcf', '5d955804', '3d2831f2', '1', '1']]"""
>>> a = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> a
[['1475367347', '72', 'c82e4f74ab2856bf', '14e87da06de28007', '1faf45a4', '83f8e8c8', '6', 'c7bd96e2', 'c7bd96e2', 'a799a5bf', '4b664dcf', '5d955804', '3d2831f2', '1', '1'], ['1475367347', '72', 'c82e4f74ab2856bf', '14e87da06de28007', '1faf45a4', '83f8e8c8', '6', 'c7bd96e2', 'c7bd96e2', 'a799a5bf', '4b664dcf', '5d955804', '3d2831f2', '1', '1']]
>>> for x in a:
...     for y in x:
...         print y
... 
1475367347
72
c82e4f74ab2856bf
14e87da06de28007
1faf45a4
83f8e8c8
6
c7bd96e2
c7bd96e2
a799a5bf
4b664dcf
5d955804
3d2831f2
1
1
1475367347
72
c82e4f74ab2856bf
14e87da06de28007
1faf45a4
83f8e8c8
6
c7bd96e2
c7bd96e2
a799a5bf
4b664dcf
5d955804
3d2831f2
1
1
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This worked. ast.literal_eval is exactly what I was missing. It basically checks if the string is "list safe" before parsing it? right?

Comment: Right, it will parse any python data structure from string safely list, dict, int  etc anything.

Comment: I tried voting for your answer bu since this is my first post and my reputation is less than 15. Stackoverflow said that it will not show my response.